# F10 key won't work in native Windows SSH client

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssh, htop

I'm using W10 2004 and I have an issue inside my remote SSH sessions using the open-ssh client natively available in Windows. My F10 key won't work inside some programs like mc or htop. In mc, I can use the esc+number shortcuts trick to simulate F keys but it doesn't work in htop for example.

Please, don't just tell me to use Putty, I know this is an option but I would really like to be able to use the native client.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you invoking this SSH session (e.g., via PowerShell, CMD, etc.). are you using Windows Terminal or another terminal emulator, and what does `echo $TERM` produce on the remote side when you run it?

Comment: I tried via powershell, CMD and the new Windows Terminal app but it doesn't work on either of these.
`echo $TERM` return : `xterm-256color`